# Self-recursive class puzzle

Tags: java, recursion

I've been wondering whether it's possible to build a self-recursive class in Java. Apparently, it is.

```
public class Void { 
    static Inher i = new Inher();

    static {
        System.out.println("ok");
    }  

    public static void main (String... args) {}

    private static class Inher extends Void {}    
}
```

However, I expected a stack overflow or some other failure, and what I get is just one "ok" in the terminal. What am I missing or getting wrong? How to straighten it up and get a proper overflow? Do you have any thoughts on this matter if not too broad?

A SMALL EXPLANATION

I wanted this code to replicate the basic class forever in the inner class, then the inner class's inner class, and so on. At some point the structure would be larger than memory. That was my failed intention.

Comment: You realize that what you might be missing is that getting "overflow" is not proper, right?

Comment: @ScottHunter This class should be a failure, but it's a double one. Can you give any exact tips to either have it sink in recursion forever or for good, or just explain why this is not possible?

Comment: You should explain why you feel this should fail. I don't see why you think it would.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Explanation added to my question.

Comment: Do you think the class loader will load `Void`, load `Inher`, then load `Void` again since `Inher extends Void`? Or do you think it'll keep creating new `Inher` objects? I'm still confused. Could you elaborate on the explanation?

Comment: I don't know this, but I would be satisfied with either. This is a part of this puzzle to me. I would like to see both "solutions".

Comment: @VinceEmigh Now I think the first version is closer to what I wanted and want to gain to see the internal inheritance in action. The other version is closer to a simple class having its objects created ad infinitum, which I know how to get. But I still would have to think of how to get this happening on the inner class level.

Comment: Aside: you shouldn't name a class `Void` as it will shadow `java.lang.Void`. It's best to use distinct names to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amongst other steps, the compiler works this way (simplified):

- Lexical analysis of the code
- Parsing of the code and building the abstract syntax tree
- Type checking
- Miscellaneous optimizations
- Generating the machine code (Java bytecode in this case)

During the type checking, the compiler will check whether the types match and exist; during the code generation, it will then create the [VMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) that will contain the list of user-defined classes.

The parsing step is only done once and works its way recursively, but it doesn't work the way you might expect it to; what it will do here is that it will see the class `Void` and add it to the list of classes, then it will check inside and see `Inher`. It sees that `Inher` extends `Void`, and `Void` is accessible from the current scope; it therefore adds this new class in the VMT.

If at any moment you had created an instance of `Inher`, it would have verified that you are within the scope of the `Void` function. But the compiler does not perform a recursive check in the sense that it will not go back to check the previous classes, and recursively generate a VMT that would overflow. It treats them separately, and based on the current context. This is why the compilation succeeds, because it is only a matter of scope and type checking.

Note that here, the `Inher` is a class declaration, and **not an instance**. If you had created a member within the `Void` class that was of the `Inher` type, with `Inher` extending `Void`, you would either have gotten a compilation failure or a stack overflow, because each allocation of a `Void` class would create a new `Inher`, which would itself allocate a new one, and so on. But here, you are only defining a class, and such an operation doesn't require a recursive construction at any moment; it therefore compiles.

At the execution, it is the same thing; the only way a stack overflow would occur is if some recursive allocation code existed; but the class definitions does not need any allocated memory, except for the VMT that was successfully built during the code generation step. So no exception of any kind can occur.

Comment: A different and perhaps simpler way to explain this is the following: your code basically means that an `Inher` is a `Void`, and you can only declare an `Inher` within the scope of `Void`. At no moment does it say that a `Void` contains an `Inher`, so no problem can arise.

Comment: Thanks. I'll read and analyse your answer tomorrow. It looks interesting.

Comment: It is late and I wrote this in a hurry, so feel free to ask if any part of it is unclear or doesn't make sense to you.

Comment: The question is about what happens at runtime.

Comment: And that is what my answer led to (see the last paragraph). However, to explain why it worked, I first had to explain why the compilation worked and specifically what it did.

Comment: This is what I looked for. I need some time to digest it though, so may have a question in the future. Thanks by now. @pie3636